# Cannot Install UnmanagedExports nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget-package, unmanagedexports

I'm new to C#, so I apologize in advance if I mix up the terminology. I seem to have a chicken-and-egg scenario regarding the UnmanagedExports nuget package. When I try to install the legacy one (1.2.7), I get an error that says, "Package Unmanaged Exports 1.2.7 is not compatible with netstandard14 (it only supports version 0.0)".

I tried to install the newer version (DllExport) and I get the same error message, except that now it says that DllExport supports version 2.0, rather than 1.4.

I feel like I'm caught in limbo between the two and I really hope it's just something simple that I'm overlooking. Thank you for considering my problem.

Comment: The error message is clunky, but the intent is clear, there is nothing "standard" about it.  You must use the proper project template to get your project started.  Which is "Class Library (.NET Framework)".  Be careful to pick the right one, there are a lot of them that start with "class library".

Comment: @HansPassant, Thank you SO much. I recreated my project and chose "Class Library (.NET Framework)" rather than the .NET Standard one and it works. If you submit this as the answer I will accept it. Thank you for taking the time to help me.